# Mongoose populate function does not populate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a User Schema and a Task Schema. (As you can see below)

When I create a task, the task's "author" field gets populated with the users ID. However, the tasks array of that user never gets any value in it, even after running .populate("tasks").

I've tried searching for a user first and then populating and vice versa. Tried looking at the mongoose docs but not sure how it works.

User Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        validate( value ) {
            if ( !validator.isEmail( value ) ) {
                throw new Error( "Email is unvalid" );
            }
        }
    },
    tasks: [ {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Task"
    } ],
    tokens: [ {
        token: {
            type: String
        }
    } ]
} );

const User = mongoose.model( "User", UserSchema, "users" );

module.exports = User;
```

Task Schema

```
const TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
} );

const Task = mongoose.model( "Task", TaskSchema, "tasks" );

module.exports = Task;
```

Creation of Task (req.user._id comes from middleware)

```
router.post( "/api/tasks", auth, async ( req, res ) => {
    const task = await new Task( {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        author: req.user._id
    } );

    task.save( ( error ) => {
        if ( error ) {
            throw new Error( error );
        }
        if ( !error ) {
            User.find( {} ).populate( "tasks" ).exec( ( error, tasks ) => {
                if ( error ) {
                    throw new Error( error );
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
    res.send( task );
} );
```

When I search for a user and then populate the tasks field, and then console.log the user, all I get is the information about the user, but the tasks array is still empty.

Am I doing something in the wrong order, or missing a step?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not done automatically. That is, Mongoose will not push to users' `tasks` array to save their tasks' IDs. You need to do that manually:

```
user.tasks.push(task);
```

More details at [Refs to children](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#refs-to-children).

Comment: Ah, i thought that was what populate did. Could you please explain to me what populate therefore does?

I will look into the docs you supplied, thank you!

Comment: Populate will take the _id(s) out of a property and will replace it with full documents loaded from the other collection based on that _id(s). In your case, users' `tasks` are still empty in the database and therefore Mongoose thinks there are no documents to load.